Early 2000 B Horror movie about a serial killer who comes back from the dead has a female cop in lead role
I have been trying for a while to find what movie this was. I have seen only parts of it. There is a serial killer with possibly super natural powers. The role of the killer is played by someone with an Indian sounding name (cant remember at this point). The movie had a few blatant rip offs from Silence of the lambs. One scene that I do remember very well is the Killer and the lady cop is inside a truck and a white worm falls out of his ears. He has also done some sort of surgery on her head where she is not capable of coherent thinking. 
Quite vague description I know, still if anyone can tell me what the movie was, it will be much appreciated.

Sounds like Unspeakable from 2002 with Dina Meyer, Dennis Hopper and Jeff Fahey.

The scientist Diana Purlow is performing experiments with the mind of criminals sentenced to death in the prison of the sadistic warden Earl Blakely. She tests an apparatus she developed and capable of read minds in a man that claims to be innocent of a murder, but she is not able to convince her former lover and Governor to call off the execution. When the serial killer Jesse Mowatt is arrested and sentenced to death, she convinces the warden to submit Jesse to her experiment. While working with the murderer, Diana faces pure evil in its essence.

The worm in people's ears is a recurring theme there, the serial killer is brought back from the dead and he's played by Indian actor and doctor Pavan Grover (who also wrote and produced the film). Here's the trailer:




You are right, you nailed it with a vague description on first try. I wish I could give you more credits/up vote.
